# AppleScript click on Safari <th> link

Tags: safari, applescript, javascript, links

Based on this HTML tag, how can I click on View from TrustedMachines?

I know how to do it from `document.getElementById` or name but not sure how to do it this cases

```
<td>
    <a data-auto-test-id="ViewTrustedMachines" href="/WebObjects/support.woa/wo/iKK52GLbH8yXxkrGGvN4M/4.4.5.53.7.5.0.447.0.0.1">View</a>
</td>
```

More complete tag:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Geo</th>
        <td>USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Download Queue</th>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Wish List</th>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Something else</th>
        <td>
            <a data-auto-test-id="ViewSomethingelse" href="/WebObjects/support.woa/wo/iKK52GLbH8yXxkrGGvN4M/4.4.5.15.1.7.0.142.0.0.1">View</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Trusted Machines</th>
        <td>
            <a data-auto-test-id="ViewTrustedMachines" href="/WebObjects/support.woa/wo/iKK52GLbH8yXxkrGGvN4M/4.4.5.53.7.5.0.447.0.0.1">View</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my normal click for id:

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('ViewTrustedMachines').click();" in tab 1 of window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Please check and fix your post so it shows the HTML part correctly.

Comment: Use query selector. Your life will always be easier in js.

Comment: This is more of js question. btw. See my answer below.

Comment: @nohillside Here Ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/wbruga37/

Comment: @jbis it's not my question :-) And even though Javascript together with AppleScript is kind of on-topic on AD answering the question probably requires primarily JS skills.

Comment: @nohillside This question will get crucified on SO. Definitely wouldn't suggest putting it there in its current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `getElementById`. Its a pain in the a** and almost never works for what you want.  Additionally none of your elements actually have id's so theres no point in use it. Instead use JavaScripts beautiful and helpful `querySelector`.  You can use CSS selectors to selector a single element and do what ever you want from there.

The element you are trying to select has a unique data attribute. The data attribute is `data-auto-test-id=` and the content of that attribute is `ViewTrustedMachines` so we can select it simply with `document.querySelector('a[data-auto-test-id="ViewTrustedMachines"]')`. Finally we just add the `.click()` to...well...click it.

```
tell application "Safari"
   do JavaScript "document.querySelector('a[data-auto-test-id=\"ViewTrustedMachines\"]').click();"
end tell
```

Also correct your HTML:

```
<table>


    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Geo</th>
            <td>USA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Download Queue</th>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Wish List</th>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Something else</th>
            <td>
                <a data-auto-test-id="ViewSomethingelse" href="/WebObjects/support.woa/wo/iKK52GLbH8yXxkrGGvN4M/4.4.5.15.1.7.0.142.0.0.1">View</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Trusted Machines</th>
            <td>
                <a data-auto-test-id="ViewTrustedMachines" href="/WebObjects/support.woa/wo/iKK52GLbH8yXxkrGGvN4M/4.4.5.53.7.5.0.447.0.0.1">View</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Finally, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/wbruga37/2/) a fiddle to show it in action.

Comment: Thank you, seems good however I can't compile , before document.querySelector you have to add do JavaScript " right?

Comment: @Kevin Yep. Fixed.

Comment: @Kevin quotes must be escaped. See above

Comment: @Kevin Glad I could help  :)